# No need for std namespace when using isalpha function

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, using

I am a beginner in C++. From what I understand, in order to use a name, we have to include the library that consist of that name. Thereafter, we can either prepend the name of the namespace or use the using keyword.

E.g.

Without using keyword:

```
std::cout << "Hello Word!" << std::endl;
```

With using keyword:

```
using namespace std;
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
```

I saw a working code sample online that uses the `isalpha` name from the `locale` library in the `std` namespace. However, that sample does not use any of the methods mentioned above.

E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
int main() {
  std::cout << isalpha('a') << std::endl;
}
```

Could someone please explain to me why the code still works?

Comment: Only if you post complete code (including headers)!

Comment: Practical C++ standard library implementations copy these C library functions into the std namespace.  But don't remove them from the global namespace.  Nor can they because that causes linker errors.

Comment: Whole magic behind `#include` is that it just copies contents of file that is included which usually contains declaration(s) of exported symbols (functions, variables), that's all.

Comment: `locale` is not the right header for that overload of `isalpha`, so you're getting it indirectly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you include a C++ header for a C library facility, that is, a header `<cfoo>` corresponding to a C header `<foo.h>`, then the names from the C library are declared in namespace `std`. However, *additionally* it is unspecified whether the names are also declared in the global namespace.

In your case it seems that they are. But you cannot rely on that, nor should you.

Comment: Sorry. I think I didn't explain clearly. I am using the c++ locale library not the one from the C library.

Comment: @LanceHAOH: It is also unspecified whether any one C++ header includes any other headers. Do not rely on magic accidents; if you need a name, include the header that declares it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two correct variants, as follows:

1. ```c++
   // C++ header
   #include <cctype>
   int main()
   {
       return !std::isalpha('a');
   }
   ```
2. ```c++
   // C header
   #include <ctype.h>
   int main()
   {
       return !isalpha('a');
   }
   ```

A compiler is permitted to declare extra names beyond those specified by the Standard, but your code is not portable if it relies on such artefacts of the implementation.

Always include the correct headers for the functions you use, and you will avoid surprises.